# Weekly Gym schedule / irregular recurring Events / D7

Tags: datetime, theming, javascript

I've been searching and trying for weeks now, but could not find a way to properly display a gym's schedule. Here is the setup:

- atm there are 3 gym branches with their own unique schedule (but using one pool of classes)
- each gym got its own node showing a schedule table/calendar
- classes recur irregular e.g. Gym-1: "Zumba" each Mo 8-9am and Fr 6-7pm (but Gym-2 with different times)
- tables only need to be editable by admins; no user interaction
- table granularity should be 15 or 30 minutes (but only showing rows with at least one item)
- also, on the front page there will be a block, showing the next class for each gym (day and time)

So I created one node for each class (e.g. "Bodypump", "Zumba",..) and added all kind of fields but can not work out how to show them in 3 independent schedules. I think it has to be 3 views but unsuccesfully tried TableField, multi-value date Fields with FullCalendar, Taxonomy,...  Is it actually possible to do this with existing modules? Pushing me in the right direction would be highly appreciated!

Note: I am not capable of programming my own modules, but at least i would know how things stand when this is becoming necessary. Also I am not a Drupal pro and might have missed the obvious.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Create content types gym1, gym2, gym3... > add suitable fields to them eg. Title and time(name the time field to field_gym1_calendar, reason for this -- see part five).
2. Create content: EXAMPLE: "content type: gym 3 --> Title: bodypump, Time: 10/10/2013 14:00-14:30".
   You can also add a taxonomy "bodypump, zumba, etc..." and add a 'Term Reference'-field to your content type (This way admin doesn't have to type 'bodypump' or 'zumba' every time he's adding stuff to calendar, just select the right one from dropdown-box)
3. Install "Date Tools" and "Date"- modules
4. Go to Views > look for button "+ Add view from template" On top of the page.
5. Search for the NAME of the TIME field you added to CONTENT TYPE gym1.
   Should look something like this: "A calendar view of the 'field_gym1_calendar' field in the 'node' base table."
6. Name this view to 'Gym 1 calendar'- for example.
7. If you have content in "gym1/......." It should be listed in "Preview" Below

Play around with "+ Add view from template" button, it creates a calendar view of any node type with -date / time- field in it (I think)

All this works in a commerce_kickstart install I'm currently f*cking with.. All the modules you need are listed in my comment... don't know. Have fun :)